# not wel formatedd(invalid token) ElementTree python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I want to parse big xml file.

While parsing I am getting net error:

```
not well-formed (invalid token): line 1508, column 87
```

Line and column might be different.

In first few cases I reformat xml, and parsing continues.

But now i can't see the reason of the error, it is needed place:

```
look_downwards_(upon?)_the_zebus_&_sevens:coroner_"the_original
```

In particular, after 'n' and before 's' in word sevens

And now I have 2 questions.

1. How can I reformat htis xml to go out from this error.
2. What i need to do, to avoid all errors, because the document is too big, and errors occur too often, and errors is not very important from human's view perspective?

P.S. I have tried this in different encoding

Comment: Post the line which has error in XML file ?

Comment: You have an unescaped ampersand. That is not allowed in an XML document. All occurrences of `&` must be replaced by `&amp;`

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan I have posted it. The second  place for code.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, And how now I can to avoid all such errors in xml, in different places it goes as needed(&quot;), in others like in case?

Comment: Where does the big input file come from? It has to be well-formed before you can parse it with any XML parser.